# MongoDB schema design for tinder like application , Embedded document or a separate collection?

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-design, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have an application in the works which needs to work in following manner :

 - When App User sets a filter and the app returns a set of quotes. 
 - Then user can like or dislike that "quote"  

We have about 60K quotes and about same number of users . 
And I am confused between using embedded array to store liked & disliked ids of the quotes or to create a separate collection and then do a lookup .
I know the 2and option will need two query and is going to be slower.

If I go using embedded array method , how many quote IDs can I store before I start witnessing performance hit because of .

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
                 fullName : {type: String,trim: true},
                 gender   : {type: String,enum: ['male', 'female']},
                 age      : {type: Number,required: true},
                 viewed   : []
});`
```

PS: If there is any better way to achieve a similar functionality , do mention in the comments or solution

**EDIT 1:** 
Thank you @niral patel for the hint.

Based on research I did on mongodb and possible solutions to this question , I devised a test where I created an array of about `10K` random numbers which in real world would `come from another collection` and passed it to a mongoose find query with `$nin` operator 
Although I anticipated the query to be slow on higher loads, in my tests it was pretty fast !

About `195 requests per second` on a *4 GB Dual core Box* running on Ubuntu 16
There were two node processes running behind a http-proxy.
My final query looked like this

```
var userIDs = [];

 // filling userIDs with random numbers
for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){
    userIDs.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (90000 - 50000)) + 50000);
}

users.find(user_id:{$nin:userIDs}}).limit(10).lean().exec(function(e,d){
    console.log(d); // results
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this informative article from mongodb.com

[6 rules of thumb for MongoDB schema](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)

if you know that amount of liked or disliked quotes will not grow more than a couple of thousands. You can have an array of quote ids in UserSchema and use populate().
This approach will also provide better performance because you only have to fire one query. I am assuming that when you show a user's information you also show his/her liked and disliked quotes. In that case this will be a better approach.

You can have a separate collection with all the ids as well if you know it will be a big amount. In that case you have to fire an extra query.

Comment: I looked into it , as many of the devs , I come from RDBMS background, going thru mongodb documentation , It mentions of aggregation framework supporting stages of computation of results, So for my case , Is a lookup in another collection possible using aggregation then ?

Comment: @Harshwardhan Yes, If you are using mongoose, you can use population. [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).